# How to maintain the order of write operations?

Tags: distributed

If service_A is sending 2 write requests, write_1 and write_2. Due to network unreliability, write_2 reaches service_B first, followed by write_1. How do we maintains the order?

If write_1 is to update new value, and write_2 is to delete the value. The arrival order is important.

I can see that this problem exists for each service-to-service interaction. But I don't see any articles talking about this issue in most microservice design book.

Answer (score 1):

Since the requests are coming from the same system, it's a trivial problem to solve. Service_A simply keeps a running counter of how many messages it has sent, and attaches the next integer ID to each message. For example, when Service_B gets a message with a write request and ID, say, 7, it won't service that request until it's received and serviced the message with ID 6. All this is similar to how other protocols, like TCP, maintain ordering.